# React starting position

Tags: reactjs, chess

Hello I am learning react.js and I choosed my project to be chess app. I was diong this for like 3 days and I still can't do it. I want to pieces be on their starting positions like king on e1 or knight g1 but I don't know how to do it. I tried doing it. My code I tried to do it is commented. But I don't know how to get them on right squares.

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Bpawn from "./pieces-basic-png/black-pawn.png"
import Bking from "./pieces-basic-png/black-king.png"
import Bqueen from "./pieces-basic-png/black-queen.png"
import Brook from "./pieces-basic-png/black-rook.png"
import Bbishop from "./pieces-basic-png/black-bishop.png"
import Bknight from "./pieces-basic-png/black-knight.png"
import Wking from "./pieces-basic-png/white-king.png"
import Wrook from "./pieces-basic-png/white-rook.png"
import Wbishop from "./pieces-basic-png/white-bishop.png"
import Wknight from './pieces-basic-png/white-knight.png';
import Wpawn from "./pieces-basic-png/white-pawn.png";
import Wqueen from "./pieces-basic-png/white-queen.png";



const horizontalLine = ["8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"];
const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
const pieces = [Bpawn, Bbishop, Bking, Brook, Bknight, Bqueen, Wking, Wrook, Wbishop, Wknight, Wpawn, Wqueen];
const squares = horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
  verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
    {
      id: `${verticals+horizontals}`,
      hor: `${horizontals}`,
      ver: `${verticals}`,
    }
  ))
));




function App() {
  function StartingPosition(piece){
    let place = ["a1"]
    // const square = document.querySelector(".square").id
    // if(piece === Bking){
    //   console.log("Bking")
    //   place = ["e8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Brook){
    //   console.log("Brook")
    //   place = ["a8", "h8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Bbishop){
    //   console.log("Bbishop")
    //   place = ["c8", "g8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Bqueen){
    //   console.log("Bqueen")
    //   place = ["d8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Bknight){
    //   console.log("Bknight")
    //   place = ["b8", "g8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Bpawn){
    //   console.log('Bpawn')
    //   place = ["a8", "b8", "c8", "d8", "e8", "f8", "g8", "h8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Wking){
    //   console.log("Wking")
    //   place = ["e1"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Wrook){
    //   console.log("Wrook")
    //   place = ["a1", "h1"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Wbishop){
    //   console.log("Wbishop")
    //   place = ["c1", "g1"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Wqueen){
    //   console.log("Wqueen")
    //   place = ["d1"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Wknight){
    //   console.log("Wknight")
    //   place = ["b8", "g8"]
    //   return place
    // }
    // else if(piece === Wpawn){
    //   console.log('Wpawn')
    //   place = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1"]
    //   return place
    // }
  }
   const Coloring = (main) => {
    let style = "black"
    if(main.ver === "a" && main.hor%2 !== 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "b" && main.hor%2 === 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "c" && main.hor%2 !== 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "d" && main.hor%2 === 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "e" && main.hor%2 !== 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "f" && main.hor%2 === 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "g" && main.hor%2 !== 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else if(main.ver === "h" && main.hor%2 === 0){
      style = "black"
    }
    else{
      style = "white"
    }
    return style
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      
      {squares.map((square) => (
        square.map((innerSquare) =>
          
         <div className='square' id={innerSquare.id} key={innerSquare.id} style={{ backgroundColor: Coloring(innerSquare) }} hor={innerSquare.hor} ver={innerSquare.ver}>{innerSquare.id}</div>,
         
      )))}
      {pieces.map((stuff) => (
        <img className="piece" src={stuff} alt={stuff} key={stuff} id={stuff} position={StartingPosition(stuff)}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.